# change bootstrap classes for selected dynamic values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to change dynamically added div sizes in to bootstrap grid cols.. i tried to change dynamically added div sizes using single click function to all added divs. but what my problem is when i clicked on added div it is changing that class,, if i selected another div to change size, but the function is applying to the previous div.. i want to change only selected div size.. you can check my code below and demo..
[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/11QYEKR00C9bh2FPblEG?p=preview)

**Updated**

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.usernames = [];
    $scope.emails = [];
  var counter = 0;
    $scope.add_username = function (index) {
        $scope.usernames[counter] = { user: 'Username', size: 'col-xs-12' };
        var userDiv =
'<div ng-click="selectUser(usernames[\'' + counter + '\']);show(\'div1\',' + counter + ')" class="{{usernames[' + counter + '].size}}" ng-class="{selected : ' + counter + ' == active}">\n\
<label>{{usernames[' + counter + '].user}}</label>//click//</div>';
        var user = $compile(userDiv)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('add')).append(user);
        $scope.changeToLarge = function () {
            $scope.username.size = 'col-xs-12';
        };
        $scope.changeToMedium = function () {
            $scope.username.size = 'col-xs-6';
        };
        $scope.changeToSmall = function () {
            $scope.username.size = 'col-xs-4';
        };
        ++counter;
    };
    $scope.selectUser = function (val) {
        $scope.username = val;
    };

    $scope.add_email = function (index) {
        $scope.emails[counter] = { email: 'Email', size: 'col-xs-12' };
        var emailDiv =
'<div ng-click="selectEmail(emails[\'' + counter + '\']);show(\'div2\',' + counter + ')" class="{{emails[' + counter + '].size}}" ng-class="{selected : ' + counter + ' == active}">\n\
<label>{{emails[' + counter + '].email}}</label>//click//</div>';
        var email = $compile(emailDiv)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('add')).append(email);
        $scope.changeToLarge = function () {
            $scope.email.size = 'col-xs-12';
        };
        $scope.changeToMedium = function () {
            $scope.email.size = 'col-xs-6';
        };
        $scope.changeToSmall = function () {
            $scope.email.size = 'col-xs-4';
        };
        ++counter;
    };
    $scope.selectEmail = function (val) {
        $scope.email = val;
    };
    $scope.show = function (arg,counter) {
        $scope.divShow = arg;
        $scope.active = counter;

    }
});
```

```css
.selected{
    background-color: #f2dede;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <button ng-click="add_username($index)">Add Username</button>
 <button ng-click="add_email($index)">Add Email</button>
 <div id="add"></div>

 <form ng-show="divShow == 'div1'">
  <label>Field Label(?)</label>
  <br/>
  <input ng-model="username.user">
 </form>
 <form ng-show="divShow == 'div2'">
  <label>Field Label(?)</label>
  <br/>
  <input ng-model="email.email">
 </form>
 <div ng-show="divShow">
  <label>Field Size(?)</label>
  <br/>
  <select>
   <option value="" disabled selected>Select Size</option>
   <option ng-click="changeToLarge()" ng-model="selected">Large</option>
   <option ng-click="changeToMedium()" ng-model="selected">Medium</option>
   <option ng-click="changeToSmall()" ng-model="selected">Small</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you are using `col-sm` so `col-sm` only work on tablet screen. So you have to use `col-xs` then it will be work fine. `col-sm` automatically will be 100% on mobile screen. so you have to use `col-xs`. https://jsfiddle.net/hamzanisar/az1mn5yq/

Comment: thats fine.. but selected div size is not changing exactly.. can u check the code once.. add username 2times then add email 2times, select on username and change size, it will change, next select on email it will change, if u want to change previously changed username size,, when u select on username if u change the size, the email size will be changed..  that is my problem